# Deadlock issue in package/update query for concurrent access

Tags: oracle, updates, deadlock, coalesce

I am using oracle package for one of the reports in out project.
When this package accessed concurrently, below query is causing deadlock.
Please suggest anyway to improve this query:

```
 UPDATE temp_final t 
 SET notnullcol = ( select COALESCE(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,h11,h12,h13,h14,h15,h16,h17,h18,h19,h20,h21,h22,h23,h23 ) 
                    from temp_final
    where (      ( rowgroup    = 'G'           and mid    = t.seid)
    or  ( rgroup    = 'K'      and  t.rgroup = rgroup  and t.mid = mid )
    or  ( rgroup    = 'G'      and  t.rgroup = rgroup and  t.mid = mid )
    )
    and rid    = t.rid
    and rtype  = t.rtype
    and sid    = t.sid
    and pid = t.pid AND rid = 9 AND rtype =1 AND sid = 'value' AND pid =  421 ) 

--5,034 rows updated.
```

Please note, temp_final is a temp table and all columns h* are used in calculation so schema of this table can not be used.

Comment: Is `temp_final` and actual temporary table, i.e. a Global Temporary Table? Or is it just a regular table with the prefix `TEMP_` in its name?

Comment: it is a temporary table, that means it does not have any sequences, no foreign key relations  and at the beginning of each report build, table data gets deleted for a particular user id.But it has been created as a normal table and not as Global Temporary table. But how does that matter here?

Comment: Which column in your UPDATE statement represents the user ID?

Comment: User Id is represented by sid

Comment: Do you have an index on SID column? Also, and I probably should have asked this earlier, what do you mean *"query is causing deadlock"*? Which error message do you get?

Comment: "There was no Oracle error, only deadlock", this information is shared by DBA .SID column does not have index as there are lot of updates on this table and index can further reduce performance.